# Why does the surface of water looks like a “frisbee from side view”?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

Here is a frisbee -

[image]

Here is a photo of the surface of water in my bottle -

[image]

(The frisbee image is taken from wikihow. )

I think, the water surface should be visible like a line but here, it looks like it has a "thickness". Is the water thick at the surface? Or is it some optical illusion?  And why is that surface bend inwards?

( I think that answer is surface tension, but that does not explain that “thickness” )

Comment: the variable curvature of the surface, causes different amounts of light to reach your eyes from different parts(some get more refracted, others less) resulting in the varying thickness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking through the meniscus at the surface of the water which is formed because of the surface tension of water.

[image]

The surface is curved because the forces of adhesion between the glass and water molecules are larger than the force of cohesion between the water molecules themselves.
This also produces the effect called capillary rise which is noticeable in tubes of small (< 5 mm) diameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i wanted to know, is the water thick there? or something else?

Comment: Have a look at the left hand drawing. You have a curved surface in play at that will change the direction of the light rays as they pass through the surface and so the amount of light which enters you eye from the boundary between the water and the air is different from the amount of light which enters your eye from other parts of your bowl.emanates from other parts of your